# Starting tomcat with SSL causes SIGSEGV, without SSL works

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, tomcat

I have a rest API created in Springboot, running on a Ubuntu server, which crashes only when launched with SSL enabled.

I created the keystore using the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat-localhost -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 3650 -keystore keystore.jks
```

I also set the following configuration:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=[path]/keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=[password]
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=p12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat-localhost
server.ssl.key-password=[password]
```

If I comment all the ssl lines, the API launches and I can request via http, but not https (as expected).

When running it in the above mentioned config I get the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.                                                                           
#                                                                                                                                                                                           
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:                                                                                                                          
#                                                                                                                                                                                           
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f35e2dec9ca, pid=4663, tid=4673                                                                                                                               
#                                                                                                                                                                                           
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (17.0.5+8) (build 17.0.5+8-Ubuntu-2ubuntu118.04)                                                                                                 
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.5+8-Ubuntu-2ubuntu118.04, mixed mode, emulated-client, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)               
# Problematic frame:                                                                                                                                                                        
# C  [libtcnative-1.so.0.2.21+0x1c9ca]  Java_org_apache_tomcat_jni_SSLContext_free+0xa                                                                                                      
#                                                                                                                                                                                           
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /var/www/vhosts/jqlifice.
de/barstool/backend/core.4663)                                                                                                                                                              
#                                                                                                                                                                                           
# An error report file with more information is saved as:                                                                                                                                   
# [path]/hs_err_pid4663.log                                                                                                                           
[thread 4664 also had an error]                                                                                                                                                             
#                                                                                                                                                                                           
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:                                                                                                                                   
#   Unknown                                                                                                                                                                                 
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.                                                                                                                       
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.                                                                                                                                        
#
```

This warning is thrown before the crash

```
WARN 4961 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.sp
ringframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start em
bedded Tomcat server
```